# Round to 1 decimal place when selecting from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am using the following code and would like to know how to round to one decimal place, IE: 2.6 instead of 3. thanks.

```
function getDistance($user_lat, $user_lng) {

    global $db, $_BASEPATH, $_DS;
    $error = '';
    $page = 0;
    $perpage = 12;
    $html = '';
    $template = '';


    $sql = ' SELECT 
                ROUND (6371 * acos( 
                        cos( radians('.$user_lat.') ) 
                        * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('.$user_lng.') ) 
                        + sin( radians('.$user_lat.') ) 
                        * sin( radians( lat ) )
                ) ) as distance 
            FROM users 
            WHERE id=' . self::ActiveUser()->id;
   
    $matches = $db->objectBuilder()->rawQuery($sql);
    // print_r($matches);exit;
    if (count($matches) <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $matches[0]->distance;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `ROUND( a_number, TothisNumberOfDecPlaces)`  I dont see the second parameter for your ROUND so it defaults to NoDecPlaces

Comment: So probably `), 2) as distance`

Comment: I didn't write the code, I added a second number and it breaks it.

Comment: @NicholasG can you share the "broken" code and the error you're getting?

Comment: Sure you added it in the right place